# Multithreading in tkinter and python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python. I am running the below code to run two threads for process something is display progress bar while the do something is running. but threading is not working for me. could you please advise? while processing this code my window is freezing when it hit do something. below is my code for your reference.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter.ttk import *
from datetime import datetime
import threading

root= tk.Tk()

def step():
    for i in range(5):
        root.update_idletasks()
        pb1['value'] += 10
        time.sleep(0.5)
        
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 600, height = 600, bg = 'lightsteelblue2', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='App1', bg = 'lightsteelblue2')
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 20))
canvas1.create_window(300, 60, window=label1)

def sel ():
    global selection
    selection = v.get()
    print(selection)

v=tk.IntVar()

R1 = tk.Radiobutton(root,  text="xyz", variable=v, value=1, command = sel, bg = 'lightsteelblue2').place(x=150, y=100)

def xyz():
        
    if selection == 1:
        t1 = threading.Thread(target = do_somthing())
        t1.start()
        
        t2 = threading.Thread(target = step())
        t2.start()
        
        t1.join()
        t2.join()

saveAsButton_Excel = tk.Button(text='do something', command=xyz, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(300, 300, window=saveAsButton_Excel)

def exitApplication():
    MsgBox = tk.messagebox.askquestion ('Exit Application','Are you sure you want to exit the application',icon = 'warning')
    if MsgBox == 'yes':
       root.destroy()
     
exitButton = tk.Button (root, text='       Exit Application     ',command=exitApplication, bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(300, 350, window=exitButton)

pb1 = Progressbar(root, orient='horizontal', length=200, mode='indeterminate')
pb1.place(x=10, y=550)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `target=do_something()` should be `target=do_something`, like `command=xyz`.  Same for `target=step()`.

Comment: do something function require arguments to be passed so I have to use ().

Comment: Then use `lambda`: `target=lambda: do_something(...)`.

Comment: [``threading.Thread`` takes both ``args`` and ``kwargs`` to pass to the function.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) You do *not* have to use ``()``.

Comment: @acw1668 I took out the brackets but still multi threading is not working. window is freezing at do_something.

Comment: Update the posted code and include `do_somthing()` code.

Comment: @acw1668 do_somthing is a parsing function that reads the excel files and parse data as per the requirement and write it back. without multithreading its working fine with no issue.                                                                                                                          
   ' if selection == 1:
        t1 = threading.Thread(target = init_pro)
        t1.start()
        
        t2 = threading.Thread(target = step)
        t2.start()
        
        t1.join()
        t2.join()  '

Comment: You should not call `.join()` as it will wait for the thread to complete.